# allow batch execution on shared folder from remote host

Tags: windows, network-share

Here is what I did until now :

I build my folders

I created the groups

I assigned the users inside the groups

I allowed this group as read/write/read+execute/etc... (temporary full permissions for testing)

Here the folder can be remotly mounted by the group members : YES

Here the folder can be remotly written with data : YES

Here the folder can be remotly written with .bat files : YES

The PROBLEM : 
now I list from the remote machine the folder is mounted on  but  I cannot execute it.

What should I missed or forgotten to do ?

[image: seems ok no?]

I test with a hello world & pause batch of course.

[image: Here is from remote host my view on folder so I can write it but not execute a batch.]

Do not hesitate if method is bad to give me cmd.exe or powershell.exe commands to be used...

Comment: What does `but I cannot execute it` mean? do you get a error message? Batch scripts can not be executed within a UNC path, as DOS never hat such things ...

Comment: Just that, it doesn't execute so no actions are taken even if I try an hello world batch